# Flutter local json list view navigation not working

Tags: json, flutter, dart, navigation, local

i have retrieving json data locally and negative to single screen in flutter
Make an asset folder in your project root directory and put my JSON file into that.
Entry the JSON file into pubspec.yaml file
Made a method to read the JSON file into your flutter application

List Screen

`import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' as rootBundle;

import 'package:license_app/data/data.dart';
import 'package:license_app/model/pqtnj_model.dart';
import 'package:license_app/page/detail.dart';

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  MyList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //final list = Pquestion.generate();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
      future: ReadJsonData(),
      builder: (context, data) {
        if (data.hasData) {
          var items = data.data as List<PjQuestion>;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade400,
                      child: Text(
                        items[index].id.toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      items[index].question.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                         return DetailScreen(snapshot.lists[index]);
                        }));
                       },
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shadowColor: Colors.black12,
                  shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                );
              });
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ));
  }

  Future<List<PjQuestion>> ReadJsonData() async {
    final jsondata =
        await rootBundle.rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/pquestion.json');
    final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;
    return list.map((e) => PjQuestion.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}`

on Tab is not navigating
the error i am getting now
"Undefined name 'snapshot'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

Detail Screen

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:license_app/data/data.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Pquestion pquestion;
  const DetailScreen(this.pquestion, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(pquestion.question),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  pquestion.answer,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

when you `tap` in the `first screen` to load the `detail screen` it actually sends a `data` with it self which you literally changed its name to `data` instead of `snapshot`, and you initialized `data` to `items` so,
try this:

```
onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                         return DetailScreen(items[index]);
                        }));
                       },
```

Comment: an error on (items[index])
"List<PjQuestion> items
The argument type 'PjQuestion' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pquestion'."

Comment: you better to specify what an individual item you send for instance `items[index].id`.